# Can't get diff between BASE and WORKING using SVNKit

Tags: diff, svnkit

I would like to use SVNDiffClient to get wc local changes,
equivalent of 'svn diff -rBASE', which is exactly what [this](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Diffing%20a%20working%20copy%20against%20a%20base%20revision) example is suposed to do.

However, running the code from example throws 'org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: At least one revision must be non-local for a pegged diff', which is exactly what [documentation](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNDiffClient.html#doDiff%28java.io.File,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNDepth,%20boolean,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.util.Collection%29) says it would.

I would like to be able to compare WORKING to BASE without hitting the server, to see if there were any changes.
Can this be accomplished using SVNKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use old API:

```
final SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
try {
    final SVNDiffClient diffClient = clientManager.getDiffClient();

    final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    diffClient.doDiff(workingCopyDirectory, SVNRevision.BASE, workingCopyDirectory, SVNRevision.WORKING, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, outputStream, null);

    System.out.println(outputStream);
} finally {
    clientManager.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use new API:

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    final SvnDiff diff = svnOperationFactory.createDiff();
    diff.setSources(SvnTarget.fromFile(workingCopyDirectory, SVNRevision.BASE), SvnTarget.fromFile(workingCopyDirectory, SVNRevision.WORKING));
    diff.setOutput(byteArrayOutputStream);
    diff.run();
```

Comment: Not an option. Project's stuck with SVNKit 1.3.2.